# Design Question: how to show number of users online?

Tags: php, mysql, web-applications

Planning to develop a LAMP web application. What general strategies can I use to display the number of users currently logged in to my site? I want to be able to accurately display something like, "There are currently 1000 users online" or "User John Doe is currently online".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A database will be involved. So every time someone logs into the site, you can have a field in a user's table for last_login. And then there can be a script that does a query against this user's table to count the number of rows last_login within the last x amount of time. It may be good to cache this and repopulate this cache every z amount of time, and then pull from this cache as oppose to running a query against the user's table every request. So database + some kind of caching system.

Comment: @FinalForm: can you please elaborate on how to do this caching? I understand your DB solution, just not so sure about the caching.

Comment: @StackOverflowNewbie ok, so obviously, it's probably not a good idea on a big website for every request for a resource, to have that resource query the database just to count right? For example, I request page A via my browser. Script A next somewhere in there does a count request for number of last logged in. That sucks. That's a N + N (page request + hard disk query request). So if you can somehow do N + (ram memory N-M) requests, that would be ideal. So maybe look into caching in memory, like mem-cache + database. It'll be more complicated, but more efficient.

Comment: @FinalForm: That sounds like premature optimization to me.  @StackOverflowNewbie: I would ignore the caching and anything performance related and get it working for now.  Once you are more familiar with how PHP/JS/HTTP all interact it will become clear how to do things in a relatively efficient way.

Comment: @Brandon I think the guy knows how the simple stuff works man. He has over 2000 points on stackoverflow. He's asking for a best practice / design. My motto: Do it right the first time, saves time in the long run.

Comment: @FinalForm: I'm not so sure since this is a 'simple stuff' type question.  I agree with your motto in principle, but if it never becomes a performance bottleneck then it's a waste of time.  For someone experienced, it's a learning experience, but it might be frustrating for a novice.  I'd worry about it getting it working first, setting up caching sometime much later.

Comment: @Brandon Thanks for the down vote on all my past posts that don't even relate to this question. :-/

Comment: @FinalForm Hey I didn't do anything like that.  If you will notice, my reputation is only 122 and you need rep of 125 to downvote.  And I wouldn't do anything like that anyway.  You obviously are an intelligent person who knows what he is talking about, I totally would love you to answer my questions.  :)

Comment: @Brandon lies :-p This is artifice at its best. Doesn't matter. I reported it. Hopefully, they'll punish whoever did this.

Comment: @FinalForm Hey, you happened to write some EXCEPTIONALLY interesting questions.  In fact I thought a few of them were worthy of an upvote.  :)

Answer (score 2):

### I recommend using the [CodeIgniter](http://codeigniter.com/) PHP framework.

This will allow you to store your session data in the database very easily (you just enable it in the config.php file).  Then you can query the number of session ids in the session table of your database.

Here is the information for the CodeIgniter session class so you can see how to use it:
[CodeIgniter Session Class](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html)

Here is also a link to the CodeIgniter forums going through more detail of how exactly to get this implemented: [CodeIgniter Forum](http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/91547/#462593)

Comment: @StackOverflowNewbie I recommend you also check out the Ion_Auth plugin, I just started using it and it has greatly simplified the tedious process of reimplementing users, administrators, and access control for each application

Answer (score 1):

This is quite easy to do, but cannot be accurate. Html being stateless,  there is no way of knowing if a user is still looking at your page or has left.

If you want to log anonymous and logged in users, you coud use a tracking cookie with a short timeout, say five minutes and have this cookie link to a database of active sessions.

Answer (score 0):

1. count the number of active sessions in your session db.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using your database to store session information, you can easily query the session table and get how many unique sessions there are stored.

Comment: Is storing session information in the DB slower than just in memory? How exactly would this be implemented? Are there any other strategies to consider?

Comment: PHP sessions aren't stored in memory. PHP stores sessions to disk by default (or at least it used to at some point) These days it's considered standard practice to save session info into a db since it's easier to access and easier to modify that doing fwrite() all over the place.  I can't say i've ever seen a performance hit caused by sessions.

Answer (score 0):

Have some sort of last accessed time record in the DB, and record that the person has been active. Then query the DB for those users who have been active in the last 5mins or so. Will give you a close approx.