# Print out current active users php

Tags: php, mysql

I have made a chat on pure php + ajax ... it's working well, however I am trying to somehow show all users that are currently logged in into my chat. I have no clue how to achieve this, but I thought that maybe I could somehow count the active sessions that is started when a user logs in into the chat. Could anyone here give me a lead on how I should do? I tried looking on other questions but none of them were able to help me with my problem.

Don't know if this helps but here is the login code where i fetch a user from the database

```
while($row = $result->fetch_object()){
if($username == $row->username)
{

        $checkPassword = password_verify($password,$row->password);
        if($checkPassword ){   
            session_start();
            $_SESSION['loggedIn'] = true; 
            $_SESSION['user'] = $row->username;
            $_SESSION['admin'] = $row->admin;
            $_SESSION['userpic'] = $row->userpic;
            $_SESSION['displayname'] = $row->displayname;
            $_SESSION['id'] = $row->id;
            header("Location:music.php?success");
            exit();
        }


}
else{
    $fail = true;
    if($fail){      
echo "<script>
alert('You typed in wrong password or username, please try again mate!');
window.location.href='music.php';
</script>";
}
}
}
```

Comment: Could you post code that gives information about the chat? Especially if it interacts with a database or monitors who is currently in the chatroom.

Comment: `$fail = false;` Note this line never gets run.

Comment: Start with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6431666/design-question-how-to-show-number-of-users-online

Answer (score 0):

Id suggest you to make a script that send request to server every 1-5 min to update last_online DB field. Then when you fetch users from DB add condition last_online less then 1-5 min from now.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you have a bug in your code. You're setting `$fail to true` and then checking `if($fail) {...}`. This code will always be running. I think you want to;

```
$fail = true;
while(users) {
  if(userName match && password check pass) {
    $fail = false;
  }
}
if ($fail) { do the error handling }
```

As far as the showing the active users, you need to define what being active means. If you update the last login time of users, then you can run a SQL query like `"SELECT userName FROM users WHERE login_time > 'calculate xx minutes ago'"`